# Bug in Keil ARM compiler with interrupt handlers and C++?

Tags: c++, interrupts, keil

I have a problem with writing interrupt handlers in Keil ARM compiler for LPC1114. When I write program in C++ and specify --cpp compiler option all code from interrupt handlers disappears, it is replaced with infinite loop. I wrote simple program that illustrates my trouble.

```
#include "LPC11xx.h"           // LPC11xx definitions
#define SYSTICK_DELAY 120000   // for 10 ms systick @ 12MHz osc

void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
  __NOP();
}

int main (void) 
{
  SystemInit();                   // from system_LPC11xx.c
  SysTick_Config(SYSTICK_DELAY);  // from core_cm0.h
  // Loop forever
  while (1) __NOP();
}
```

When trying to compile this code with --cpp compiler option I get infinite loop in disasm:

```
SysTick_Handler PROC
            EXPORT  SysTick_Handler           [WEAK]
            B       .
            ENDP
```

This is the place where __NOP() from above program must be. And it is there when I'm compiling code with --c99 compiler option or without additional options. Keil MDK version is 4.12. Can anyone tell me is there any solution or workaround ?

Comment: As your ISR does nothing is it just being optimized away?  Perhaps you could try disabling optimization or declaring something `volatile` in it.

Comment: Optimization is set to -level0, Optimize for Time - deselected. __NOP() is not nothing. But I also tried changing global vars in interrupt handler or calling for functions. The code provided above was simplified to be just so small to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Filed a technical support request to Keil, will repost here any answer.

Comment: Why do you need an __NOP(); call?  Can't you just use a simple semicolon?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The "weak" reference just means that the routine will be replaced by a routine in your code of the same name.  When using C this is simple, the names will always be identical but C++ name mangles the functions (for function overloading etc) so the compiled name will probably not match the default ISR name.  You need to wrap the function (or at least a forward reference, I'm not sure of specifics I mostly work in C) in an extern "C" wrapper to force the compiler to not mangle the name.

```
extern "C" {
  void SysTick_Handler(void)
  {
    // do whatever
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works exactly as you wrote in example. And also I can declare function in header file as 
    extern "C" void SysTick_Handler(void); 
and later write my interrupt handler in classical form i.e. without extern "C".

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you for this great answer! So much time was wasted because of not knowing this ) Thank you once more!