# Why isn't my SysTick_Handler() being called in my LPCxpresso C++ Project?

Tags: lpc, lpcxpresso

I have created a C++ project for an LPC1227 using LPCExpresso 6.1.0.  The project, up until now, builds and runs fine.  I have not made any changes to `cr_startup_lpc12xx.cpp`.

I would like to add a `SysTick_Handler()`.  In my `main.cpp` I have added a method:

```
void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
    timerCounter++;  // these variables are all declared globally in main.cpp
    timer_10ms_tick = true;
    if ((timerCounter % 10) == 0)  //every 100ms
    {
        timer_100ms_tick = true;
    }
    if ((timerCounter % 100) == 0)  //every 1000ms
    {
        timer_1000ms_tick = true;
    }
}
```

I have also add the following line in my `main()` method:

```
SysTick_Config(12000000/100);
```

When I run my code via debug, the interrupt is firing, but it is getting stuck in the default `SysTick_Handler()` that is inside of `cr_startup_lpc12xx.cpp` (which is just an infinite while loop).   If I delete the default `SysTick_Handler` from `cr_startup_lpc12xx.cpp`, my program hard faults.

I have looked at the Blinky example (which is C, not C++) and it adds a new handler into `main.cpp` without deleting the handler from the startup file.

Can anyone suggest why my overriding handler is not being called?  Is this a C++ difference?

Comment: If you change to normal c file does it work? If you change Blinky example to c++ do you get the same problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://rowley.zendesk.com/entries/20986562-LPC1114-IRQ-Handlers-in-C-work-in-C-do-not-work

> You need to declare your interrupt handler as a C function otherwise
>   the function will not override the default handler.
>
> So for example you could do something like the following to make the
>   declaration work in both C or C++:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void irq_handler();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I assume changing `irq_handler()` in the code above to your `SysTick_Handler` code will then work. e.g.

```
extern "C" {
    void SysTick_Handler(void)
    {
        timerCounter++;  // these variables are all declared globally in main.cpp
        timer_10ms_tick = true;
        if ((timerCounter % 10) == 0)  //every 100ms
        {
            timer_100ms_tick = true;
        }
        if ((timerCounter % 100) == 0)  //every 1000ms
        {
            timer_1000ms_tick = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is true of C++, but in C the default handler must be declared as a `weak` function in the default declarations. This allows another declaration to override the original one, so your custom handler should *not* have the weak attribute.

Comment: True.  It is declared weak.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem once. Yes it is C++ vs C difference. Looks like the maintainers of LPC support libraries did not care for C++ developers. Full answer is here [Bug in Keil ARM compiler with interrupt handlers and C++?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7660/bug-in-keil-arm-compiler-with-interrupt-handlers-and-c)