# STM32F411VE ADC interrupt not working

Tags: adc, stm32, interrupts

My code works fine without interrupt (I tried polling the ADC value) but when I enabled the interrupt, it didn't work - while debugging in Keil, it never reaches the `ADC_IRQHandler()`, Also I found that the EOC flag is always set(in the while loop)

This is my code:

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"                  // Device header
volatile int16_t k=0;
int main()
{

RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIODEN | RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN ;
RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_ADC1EN;

GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE0; //analog input
GPIOA->PUPDR &=~ GPIO_PUPDR_PUPD0; 
GPIOD->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE13_0;//ouput
GPIOD->MODER &=~ GPIO_MODER_MODE13_1;
GPIOD->OTYPER &=~ GPIO_OTYPER_OT13;
GPIOD->OSPEEDR |= GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR13_0 ;
GPIOD->PUPDR &=~ GPIO_PUPDR_PUPD13 ;
GPIOD->ODR &=~ GPIO_ODR_OD13;

ADC1->CR2 |= ADC_CR2_ADON | ADC_CR2_CONT;
ADC1->SMPR2 |= ADC_SMPR2_SMP0_1;
ADC1->SQR3 &=~ ADC_SQR3_SQ1_4; //CHANNEL 0 (PA0)
ADC1->CR1 |= ADC_CR1_EOCIE;
NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC_IRQn);
NVIC_SetPriority(ADC_IRQn,0);
ADC1->CR2 |= ADC_CR2_SWSTART;

while(1)
{
}

}
void ADC_IRQHandler()
{
     k= ADC1->DR;
     if(k>2000)
     {
        GPIOD->ODR ^= GPIO_ODR_OD13;
     }
}
```

Comment: a guess: you yo need to set or clear an interrupt flag?  do you need to associate ADC_IRQHandler with a specific interrupt?

Comment: I tried to clear the eoc flag but it didn't work. I want to run a simple adc interrupt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i must add this `extern "C"` because i'm in c++ not in c :

```
    extern "C" {
     void ADC_IRQHandler()
     {
           // do whatever
     }
    }
```

this is the complete answer :[Bug in Keil ARM compiler with interrupt handlers and C++?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7660/bug-in-keil-arm-compiler-with-interrupt-handlers-and-c)